# ActiveX CAB file license information

Tags: activex

I want to license a ActiveX component from a software vendor. His usual licensing model is that the ActiveX component will have to installed on individual computers. Since my web-based application is for public access, I asked him to provide a digitally signed CAB file of his ActiveX component. His concern is that somebody might be able to extract the license key from the cab file and re-use it somewhere else. Are there any suggestion to address his concern?

Answer (score 1):

A certificate isn't like an encrypted key that only Internet Explorer can interpret, that would be pointless since everything can be reverse engineered.

This works on another way: Internet Explorer gets the signed CAB file, extracts its certificate and, if the referenced certification authority is in the list of valid ones, it will ask if the current certificate is valid for the domain, for the cab and for the ActiveX control. That way it's pointless to steal a certificate.

Comment: I believe software vendor's concern is that the license key (which will be part of the INF file) will be exposed to the public domain and somebody could misuse it..